# Variance of the inner product of independent vectors

Tags: probability, variance

> **Note**: I am *not* asking about the interpretation of covariance as an inner product on the space of random variables.

I have two $n$-dimensional random variables $\vec X, \vec Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Each has some covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\vec X}, \Sigma_{\vec Y}$.
Each is also "nice", namely

1. $\vec X\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I_n)$, and
2. $\vec Y\gets \mathsf{Unif}(K)$ for a compact convex set $K$.

I want to compute $\mathsf{Var}(\langle \vec X, \vec Y\rangle)$.
Is there a simpler way to do this than via explicitly working with the density of $\langle \vec X, \vec Y\rangle$?
For example, is it some function of $\Sigma_{\vec X}, \Sigma_{\vec Y}$?

Comment: Did you mean $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,\Sigma_X)$? Also, can we assume $X$ is independent of $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent (your post doesn't say so, but your title does). Then taking $X\sim N(0,\Sigma_X),Y\sim \text{Unif}(K)$ as column random vectors, we have

$$\begin{align}V(X'Y)&=E[X'YY'X]-(E[X'Y])^2\\
&=E[X'YY'X]-(\underbrace{E[X']}_{=0}E[Y])^2 \quad (\text{by indep})\\
&=\text{tr}E[X'YY'X]\\
&=E[\text{tr}(X'YY'X)]\\
&=E[\text{tr}(XX'YY')]\\
&=\text{tr}E[XX'YY']\\
&=\text{tr}E[XX']E[YY'] \quad (\text{by indep})\\
&=\text{tr}(\Sigma_X(\Sigma_Y+\mu_Y\mu_Y'))\\
\end{align}$$

where $\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y$ are respectively mean and covariance matrix of $Y$.

If $\Sigma_X=\sigma^2I_n,$ then this simplifies to

$$\sigma^2\text{tr}(\Sigma_Y+\mu_Y\mu_Y').$$